# WebView content (website) at Android device to large

Tags: android, webview

I crated an Android app with webview. In Android simulator I can scroll out the website, till it match perfekt the webview. But at a real Android device, I'm not able to scroll out till the website content matches the webwiew, it is to large. What co do I have to put/change to get the website match the webview?

I hope you understand my issue und can help me!?

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

if you mention above settings ,webview can render your website properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Add this in MainFragment.java?

Comment: can you post your code,mention those setting after web view initialization

Comment: Which file? MainFragment.java? AndroidManifest.xml? …?

Comment: fragment and layout file

Comment: delete your answers and update the question with code

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/sample/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/samples/PullToRefreshWebViewActivity.java  -refer this link

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:webviewapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/global_bg_front" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_adview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            webviewapp:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
            webviewapp:adSize="BANNER" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_progress"
        android:id="@+id/container_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_offline"
        android:id="@+id/container_offline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_empty"
        android:id="@+id/container_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:webviewapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/global_bg_front" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_adview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            webviewapp:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
            webviewapp:adSize="BANNER" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_progress"
        android:id="@+id/container_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_offline"
        android:id="@+id/container_offline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_empty"
        android:id="@+id/container_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>









<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/drawer_item_divider"
        android:divider="@color/drawer_item_divider"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@color/drawer_bg" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```